# chromedp ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

Tags: go, chromedp

I want to login to a website. The second I get to the URL it shows me a prompt to login with a username and password.

I cannot fill them in with ChromeDP. It won't even load the page.

Currently I am getting the error:

> ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

Tried to log in various ways but I am unable to fill in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I found it out.

> https://usr:pass@mywebsite.com/

Is what can be used.